# How to capture the client's connections and disconnections at the server side?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-client, net.tcp

I have written a server/client using WCF (net.tcp). Now I want to capture the client's connections and disconnections at the server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you have got authentication built within your WCF with slight modification this can be achieved.

You create 2 methods on the service (Connect, Disconnect), where Connect is the first thing called by the client on startup (or logon) and Disconnect the last method client executes. On the server you log the connections/disconnections to database or any other storage of your choice.

This is simple and does what you need. However, if the client app ends with unexpected exception or there are network issues you will not know that it happened. This is why I would add another method on the server that is called Refresh. The way this would work - every time client calls connect, you start a background thread on a timer and run Refresh every 5 minutes. This way your server side logs activity of the client at least every 5 minutes. Also I would create a Windows service running on the server on a timer every 10 minutes and if there are any not refreshed connection it creates a forced Disconnect.

So this is how high level code on server would work:

```
  [DataContract]
public class Session
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public byte[] passwordHash { get; set; }
    public Guid sessionGuid { get; set; }
}

        public bool Connect(Session sessionObject)
    {
        if (GetOpenSession(sessionObject.sessionGuid) == null)
        {
            if (CreateNewSession(sessionObject)) return true; else return false;

        }
        else
        {
            CloseSession(GetOpenSession(sessionObject.sessionGuid));
            if (CreateNewSession(sessionObject)) return true; else return false;
        }
    }

    public void Disconnect(Guid sessionGuid)
    {
        if (GetOpenSession(sessionGuid) != null)
        {
            CloseSession(GetOpenSession(sessionGuid));
        }
    }

    public bool Refresh(Guid sessionGuid)
    {
        if (GetOpenSession(sessionGuid) != null)
        {
            UpdateSession(sessionGuid);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false; 
        }
    }
```

On the client if Connect or Refresh return false it would mean that connection has been lost and user needs to reconnect (re-login);

Comment: Can you tell me more about GetOpenSession, CreateNewSession,CloseSession and UpdateSession. thank`s for your help.

Comment: CreateNewSession - in the simplest implementation you authenticate the user against password in the database and if it it succeeds you create a session record in the database using guid passed by client as unique value. GetOpenSession - you query sessions table using guid and if it is an open session you return the session object. Close session - update database, change SessionOpen field to False. Update Session updates LastDateTimeRefreshed field with current date time (this is when user is still logged in).

Comment: Can you give me a simple example with code. It will be really helpful for me because i am new in WCF.